# My "Cider" has the consistency of puree - what to do?

Tags: fermentation, cider

3 weeks ago, I set up a batch of apple to make hard cider. I chopped the apples in a kitchen machine and added yeast. The yeast I put into a smaller batch of the mashed apples before, after ading some sugar there was vissible fermentation (bubbles). For most of the three weeks, I guess the fermentation went ok - there were always visible bubbles in the water lock. For a few days to one week, there's hardly any bubbles forming, so I figured the fermentation is done.

When I tried racking the cider today, it was too thick and I could only get a small amount through the racking tube. It is more liquid when I set it up, but still very thick.

The little bit I got through the tube, I filtered with a tea filter. The liquid is turbid, tastes slightly yeasty, sour and is definitly alcoholic.

Maybe an overreaction, but to kickstart the fermentation again I added a bit of sugar (maybe 2 tablespoons to 5kg apples) and shook the vessel to mix the stuff.

My father uses the same apples, he usually gets a clear liquid over a sediment of apples and yeast. He uses high performance yeast and adds lots of sugar to make booze.

The vessel ist standing in my kitchen with some temperature swings between day and night. The yeast I'm using is adopted to lower temperatures.

Now, what has happended and what can I do?
I'm thinking of filtrating the cider through a cloth, would this be a way to go?
What experiences have others made when femrenting from a puree?

**Edit to add:**
My father, from whom I got the idea brew from puree, uses to add enzmes (Pektinase). Aparantly that's the trick.

Comment: Do I understand that you fermented the solids in rather than extracting the juice from them first? If so, you might need to squeeze out the cider through cheesecloth.

Comment: Fermentation from solids, correct. will look for a cheesecloth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add some apple juice instead of sugar to restart fermentation, and it would "dilute" the stuff too. Then, filter the stuff, then you should get a decent hard cider.

Comment: I actually decided to filter without adding juice first, worked out reasonable.